# Lagging ScrollView with UIWebview inside

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview inside a UIScrollview with a lot of content.
When the content loaded by the UIWebView is really big, its starts to lag.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Keep in mind that it only lags when the UIWebview's height becomes considerably big.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation on `UIWebView`, it specifically states **NOT** to embed a `UIWebView` into a `UITableView` or a `UIScrollView`. Doing so leads unexpected behaviour, and I think you are experiencing this first hand. Sorry to be bearer of bad news.

**Update - Specific Warning From Apple Docs**:

The documentation addresses this issue specifically.

> **Important**: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

[Apple reference on `UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**UPDATE 2**:

After doing a few searches ([search link](https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=UIWebView+embed+in+UIScrollView&oq=UIWebView+embed+in+UIScrollView&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.3063.11700.0.11824.31.18.0.13.13.0.154.1837.11j7.18.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.073vyaetpTk&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1352&bih=841&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b), same as what posted in the comments), I came across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7746808/620197), which may provide some insight. It basically monitors the content offset in both the `UIScrollView` and `UIWebView` via delegates, and some clever user use of `[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:]`. There are a few drawbacks though (i.e. links may not work as expected). But a warning, we do not control the internal implementations of either of these classes, and future iOS updates may break your solution.

Comment: Workarounds may exist mate. That's why I ask here. It works perfectly as intended as long as the content loaded isn't too big.

Comment: @Ancientar True, but warnings in official documentation exist for a reason. There is probably conflict occuring when the OS is trying to decide where send the scroll events.

Comment: Not in this case. The scrollview doesn't actually lag that much. Even if the UIwebview several thousands of pixels in height. I just thought I'd ask incase someone knew of a way to fix this.

Comment: @Ancientar It has been asked quite a lot ([link](https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=UIWebView+embed+in+UIScrollView&oq=UIWebView+embed+in+UIScrollView&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.3063.11700.0.11824.31.18.0.13.13.0.154.1837.11j7.18.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.073vyaetpTk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42261806,d.dmg&fp=6c5931f54eec81f3&biw=1352&bih=841)), and all answers say the same thing, don't do it. That being said, there may work arounds by writing completely custom views and and handling the touch events yourself. As for the question as stated, it is not recommended.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the uiwebview is just a subview of a UIview thats a sunview to the scrollview, so misshandling touches is not an issue. Its the constantly drawing of the UIWebview I believe.